# Why Export Dynamics CRM 365 solution is throwing this error?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am getting this error while exporting a solution in Dynamics CRM 365 8.2 on-premise.

> The Web Service plug-in failed in OrganizationId: 3f5faf77-6c61-df11-aff8-00155d0a4610; SdkMessageProcessingStepId: 681f0f11-8e01-40a1-8d84-424242bb392c; EntityName: none; Stage: 30; MessageName: ExportSolution; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   Inner Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.RootExportHandler.InitializeWorkflowHandlers(List`1 solutionComponentWorkflowSet, List`1 solutionComponentEntitySet)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.RootExportHandler.AddExportHandlers(Dictionary`2 solutionComponetSets, List`1 solutionComponentEntitySet, Guid solutionId, Boolean foundApplicationRibbonComponent, Boolean foundSiteMapComponent)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.RootExportHandler.InitializeExportHelpers()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.RootExportHandler.RunExport()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.ExportXmlService.ExportSolutionWithTargetVersion(String solutionName, Boolean managed, String targetVersion, Boolean exportAutoNumberingSettings, Boolean exportCalendarSettings, Boolean exportCustomizationSettings, Boolean exportEmailTrackingSettings, Boolean exportGeneralSettings, Boolean exportMarketingSettings, Boolean exportOutlookSynchronizationSettings, Boolean exportRelationshipRoles, Boolean exportIsvConfig, Boolean exportSales, Boolean exportExternalApplications, ExecutionContext context)

Comment: Do you have a custom plugin registered on the ExportSolution message?

Comment: I am creating a new solution to export in that I just added case and few fields, thats it. When I am trying its throwing an error. No plugins added to export. But custom plugins are there.

Comment: Try this: disable all plugin steps and deactivate all actions and workflows. Publish all customizations. Enable tracing on the server and export the solution.